# How can I set up an extended desktop on multiple monitors in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

How can I set up an extended desktop on two monitors on Windows 7? I have a laptop and an external monitor with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up an extended desktop in Windows 7 (and 8) is simpler than with older versions of Windows. First, push <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to pop up the display menu and choose "Extend" to enable the extended desktop. Then, right-click the desktop and choose "Screen resolution" and ensure that the screen resolution for the external monitor is correct. Lastly, drag the monitor symbols in the window to the way that you have in your setup, and you're done.